# ¿Cuál es el origen de estos significados de «juego»?

Tags: etimología

*Juego*, además de su significado más sencillo, se puede entender como cosas que guardan relación entre sí:

> *Un juego de cartas*.
>
> *El traje hace juego con el maletín.*

Pero ¿cuál es el origen de este significado de *juego*?

Answer (score 3):

El [origen etimológico](https://archive.org/stream/diccionariogener04echeuoft#page/30/mode/2up) es el mismo, el latín *[iocus](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/iocus)* (broma, chanza); "juego" como "conjunto de cosas que guardan relación entre sí" se usa también en catalán, francés e italiano (*joc*, *jeu* y *gioco* respectivamente): hasta ahí lo que puedo decir con fundamento. El hecho de que en latín no tuvo al parecer ese significado me hace pensar que este surgió de alguna de estas lenguas, y pienso que habrá tenido su origen en "juego" como "conjunto de cartas" o "conjunto de elementos necesarios para la práctica de un juego" (acepciones 6 y 7 del [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/jeu/44887)).